# How to resume RMI communication after a program shuts down and restarts while the other remains running in Java?

Tags: java, rmi

So I currently have a lot of code, it will be difficult to break it all down into an SSCCE but maybe I will attempt to do so later if necessary.

Anyways, here is the gist: I have two processes communicating via RMI. It works. However I want to be able continue if the communcation if the host process (JobViewer) exits and then returns all in the life of the client process (Job).

Currently I have the binded name saved to a file everytime a Job starts up, and the JobViewer opens this file on startup. It works great, the correct binded name works. However, I get a `NotBoundException` every time I try to resume communication with a Job that I know for fact is still running when the JobViewer restarts.

My JobViewer implements an interface that extends Remote with the following methods:

```
public void registerClient(String bindedName, JobStateSummary jobSummary) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException;
public void giveJobStateSummary(JobStateSummary jobSummary) throws RemoteException;
public void signalEndOfClient(JobStateSummary jobSummary) throws RemoteException;
```

And my Job also implements a different interface that extends Remote with the following methods:

```
public JobStateSummary getJobStateSummary() throws RemoteException;
public void killRemoteJob() throws RemoteException;
public void stopRemoteJob() throws RemoteException;
public void resumeRemoteJob() throws RemoteException;
```

How do I achieve this? Here is some of my current code that inits the RMI if it helps...

JobViewer side:

```
private Registry _registry;
// Set up RMI
_registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2002);
_registry.rebind("JOBVIEWER_SERVER", this);
```

Job side:

```
private NiceRemoteJobMonitor _server;

Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(hostName, port);
registry.rebind(_bindedClientName, this);
Remote remoteServer = registry.lookup(masterName);

_server = (NiceRemoteJobMonitor)remoteServer;
_server.registerClient(_bindedClientName, _jobStateSummary);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution was to have the Job ping the JobViewer every so often:

```
  while (true) {

    try {

      _server.ping();
      // If control reaches here we were able to successfully ping the job monitor.

    } catch (Exception e) {

      System.out.println("Job lost contact with the job monitor at " + new Date().toString() + " ...");

      // If control reaches we were unable to ping the job monitor.  Now we will loop until it presumably comes back to life.
      boolean foundServer = false;
      while (!foundServer) {

        try {

          // Attempt to register again.
          Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(_hostName, _port);
          registry.rebind(_bindedClientName, NiceSupervisor.this);
          Remote remoteServer = registry.lookup(_masterName);
          _server = (NiceRemoteJobMonitor)remoteServer;
          _server.registerClient(_bindedClientName, _jobStateSummary);

          // Ping the server for good measure.
          _server.ping();

          System.out.println("Job reconnected with the job monitor at " + new Date().toString() + " ...");

          // If control reaches here we were able to reconnect to the job monitor and ping it again.
          foundServer = true;

        } catch (Exception x) {

          System.out.println("Job still cannot contact the job monitor at " + new Date().toString() + " ...");

        }

       // Sleep for 1 minute before we try to locate the registry again.
        try {
          Thread.currentThread().sleep(PING_WAIT_TIME);
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {

        }

     } // End of endless loop until we find the server again.

   }

    // Sleep for 1 minute after we ping the server before we try again.
    try {
      Thread.currentThread().sleep(PING_WAIT_TIME);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }

  }  // End of endless loop that we never exit.
```

Comment: Indiscriminate repetition on any arbitrary exception can't be recommended as a solution. You should repeat on most but not all RemoteExceptions. Various other exceptions such as NOE would indicate a bug in your code rather than an occasion for retry. And I repeat that a client doesn't need to bind itself to a Registry at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I get a `NotBoundException` every time I try to resume communication with a Job that I know for fact is still running when the JobViewer restarts.

That can only happen if the `JobViewer` didn't rebind itself when it started up. More usually you get a `NoSuchObjectException` when you use a stale stub, i.e. a stub whose remote object has exited. In this case you should reaquire the stub, i.e. redo the `lookup()`.

Why is the client binding itself to a Registry? If you want to register a callback, just pass `this` to the `registerClient()` method instead of the bind-name, and adjust its signature accordingly (using the client's remote interface as the parameter type). No need to have the server doing a lookup to the client Registry. No need for a client Registry at all.